# woocommerce - changing the customs attributes of a product, and facing update_post_meta() incrementing none unique '_product_attributes'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product, custom-taxonomy

My problem is mostly in the understanding of *update_post_meta()*, and the use of none unique meta field.

```
$res = add_post_meta( $model_id, '_model_email', sanitize_email( $post_data ), TRUE );
    if( $res === false ) {
      update_post_meta( $model_id, '_model_email', sanitize_email( $post_data ) );
}
```

Basically, *_model_email* is forced to unique key, but not _product_attributes. *_model_email* shows correctly, but *_product_attributes* indefinitly through new stack on the void pile, changes no where to be seen again.

Can you tell me what is the purpose of a none unique field ? 
Is it possible to find them ? 
Is it safe to change '_product_attributes' to unique while creating the new custom product ?